# How can i get item data when clicked widget ListView

Tags: android, listview, widget

I created a `ListView` on homescreen widget but I clicked the item of `ListView` I can't get correct position data from `ListView`. How can I do it?

**WidgetProvider.class**

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static final String TOAST_ACTION = "com.mobistech.mobistechsmart.Widget.TOAST_ACTION";
    public static final String MERCHANT_ITEM = "com.mobistech.mobistechsmart.Widget.MERCHANT_ITEM";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                    appWidgetIds[i]);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }



        private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {

        //which layout to show on widget
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);

        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

        svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget,
                svcIntent);
        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.listViewWidget, R.id.empty_view);


        //When item is clicked on ListView



        Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context, BroadCast.class);
        PendingIntent startActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listViewWidget, startActivityPendingIntent);

        return remoteViews;
    }

}
```

**WidgetService.class**

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
    /*
     * So pretty simple just defining the Adapter of the listview
     * here Adapter is ListProvider
     * */

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

        return (new ListProvider(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
    }
}
```

**ListProvider.class**

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {
    private List<Device> listItemList = new ArrayList<Device>();
    private Context context = null;
    private int appWidgetId;

    public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

        populateListItem();
    }

    private void populateListItem() {
        DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(context);
        listItemList=db.getAllDevices();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /*
     *Similar to getView of Adapter where instead of View
     *we return RemoteViews
     *
     */
    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

        final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
                context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);
        Device device = listItemList.get(position);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.row_txt,device.getName());
        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.row_image, context.getResources().getIdentifier(device.getIconName(), "drawable", context.getPackageName()));


        Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
        fillInIntent.putExtra(WidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION, position);
        remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.row_txt, fillInIntent);


        return remoteView;
    }


    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help, it is a possible duplicate of this question - [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195035/android-start-activity-from-app-widget-with-listview-and-service)

Comment: It didn't help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new SingleItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                }
            });
```

The position field from this function is all that is required